# Accessing the primary key in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, local-storage, indexeddb

I am trying to print the objects primary key in IndexedDB to the console.

I've seen two examples that use 'Cursor.Value.Key' but when I use that I get 'undefined'.

```
if (cursor) 
    {
        console.log(cursor.value.key);
        console.log(cursor.value.username);
        console.log(username)
        console.log(cursor.value.password);
        console.log(password)
```

This is my database

```
objectStore = db.createObjectStore('users', { keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true });
    objectStore.createIndex('username', 'username', { unique: true });
    objectStore.createIndex('password', 'password', {unique: false});
```

It should print the objects primary key, ie 1 or 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cursor.key` (or `cursor.primaryKey` for an index rather than an object store) or `cursor.value.id`. `cursor.value` is the object itself, so `cursor.value.key` would only return the primary key if you had keyPath set to "key".